# liminf of sequence of iid random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf, independence

if $P(\liminf (X_n>a))=0$, does that mean $\liminf X_n <a$ almost surely? Where $X_n$ are iid random variables.

Comment: Hint: Compare $<$ and $>$ with $\leqslant$ and $\geqslant$.

Comment: @Did, May I please get more hints? I have been stuck on this for days.

$P(\liminf (X_n>a))=0$ means for almost all of $\omega \in \Omega$, $X_n(\omega) \le a$ happens for a later n>N, no matter what N you choose. What does that tell us about  $\liminf X_n$?

Comment: Try $X_n=0$ for all $n$.  With the Did hint.

Comment: @Michael  I think I have $P(\liminf (X_n>a))=0$ means $\lim inf X_n \ge a$ almost surely

Comment: Not quite, actually, $$\limsup\{X_n\leqslant a\}\subseteq\{\liminf X_n\leqslant a\},$$ hence $$P(\liminf\{X_n>a\})=0\implies P(\liminf X_n\leqslant a)=1.$$

Comment: oh right! Thank you so much.

Comment: Rann, edited answer

Answer (score -1):

Important inequalities

Williams - Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

Deduced similarly:

(iii) If $\liminf x_n > z$, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n > z)$ eventually (that is, for infinitely many n)

(iv) If $\liminf x_n < z $, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n < z)$ infinitely often (that is, for infinitely many n)

---

> if $P(\liminf (X_n>a))=0$, does that mean $\liminf X_n <a$ almost surely?

Note that $P(\liminf (X_n>a))=0 \iff P(\limsup (X_n \le a))=1$

Now it is not true that

$$P(\limsup (X_n \le a))=1 \to P(\liminf X_n <a) = 1$$

Consider $X_n = a - 1/n$.

However

$$P(\limsup (X_n \le a))=1 \to P(\liminf X_n \le a) = 1$$

The contrapositive is

$$P(\liminf X_n > a) = 1 \to P(\liminf (X_n > a))=1$$

This can proven by proving

$$\liminf X_n > a \subseteq \liminf (X_n > a)$$

Pf: Suppose

$$\sup_{m \ge 1} \inf_{n \ge m} X_n := \beta > a$$

Then $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists m \ge 1$ s.t.

$$\inf_{n \ge m} X_n := \alpha_m \in (\beta - \epsilon, \beta]$$

Choose $\epsilon > 0$ s.t.

$$\inf_{n \ge m} X_n := \alpha_m > a$$

$$\to \inf (X_m, X_{m+1}, ...) := \alpha_m > a$$

$$\to X_n \ge \alpha_m > a \ \forall n \ge m \ QED$$

Comment: Number 4 at the top of your answer is opposite of what Did said. So I am confused.

Comment: @Rann I don't see how #4 contradicts anything Did said. What did Did say that seems to contradict?

Comment: Did said $\limsup\{X_n\le a\} \subseteq \liminf X_n \le a $, which I believe is opposite of what you said in #4

Comment: @Rann I don't see how they are opposites. That statement is the contrapositive of #3. The statement of Did is what I am proving in this answer

Comment: I believe in your #4, you were saying $\liminf X_n \le a \subseteq \limsup \{X_n\le a \}$

Comment: @Rann I wasn't. #4 is really a strict Inequality. Try proving #4 yourself like I proved contrapositive of #3